# Not sprint while crouching?

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

So I'm in the early stages of making an FPS game and I've just implemented a sprint and crouch function (crouch only slows the player down at the moment).
the functions are simply this:

```
private void sprintInput()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(sprintKey))
    {           
        movementSpeed *= 2f;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(sprintKey))
    {          
        movementSpeed /= 2f;
    }
}


private void crouchInput()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(crouchKey))
    {           
        movementSpeed /= 2f;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(crouchKey))
    {
        movementSpeed *= 2f;
    }
}
```

However written like this, they can obviously be activated both at the same time. But I want crouch to overwrite sprint. So if I use sprint and crouch at the same time, only crouch is activated.
I've tried multiple methods but nothing works, I'm sure that I'm missing something painfully obvious, I just don't know what.

Comment: `&& !crouching`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a boolean variable to true/false when crouching or not.

```
bool isCrouching;

private void crouchInput()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(crouchKey))
    {        
        isCrouching = true;   
        movementSpeed /= 2f;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(crouchKey))
    {
        isCrouching = false; 
        movementSpeed *= 2f;
    }
}
```

You can then use that variable to make sure you're not crouching before sprinting:

```
private void sprintInput()
{
    if (!isCrouching  && Input.GetKeyDown(sprintKey))
    {           
        movementSpeed *= 2f;
    }
    if (!isCrouching && Input.GetKeyUp(sprintKey))
    {          
        movementSpeed /= 2f;
    }
}
```

The sprinting modifier will only be available to be activated whenever the crouching var/button isn't in use.

Comment: Your crouching code was not complete since you're not setting it anywhere. Had to edit it to add that.

Comment: No worries, I didn't realise I had to write out the entire solution! I'm also wondering why the double declaration of (!isCrouching...) is better than a single container to the same effect?

Comment: You didn't have to write out entire code. Just show the important parts which is where and when to write to isCrouching  and when to read from it. That's it. The double declaration of isCrouching is not better or bad. It just keeps the code very close to the way the original code is and teaches op the use of `&&`.  To avoid too many `if` statements, you will have to use `&&` t o simplify your code. You can change it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer actually makes an exploit in your game. Player will press sprint (speed x2), press crouch (speed /2), release sprint (*nothing happens*), then release crouch (speed x2), which doubles his speed permanently.

More correct approach I think will be storing both flags:

```
bool isCrouching, isSprinting;
float baseSpeed, movementSpeed;

private void sprintInput {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(sprintKey)) {        
        isSprinting = true;
        UpdateSpeed ();
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(sprintKey)) {
        isSprinting = false; 
        UpdateSpeed ();
    }
}

private void crouchInput {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(crouchKey)) {        
        isCrouching = true;
        UpdateSpeed ();
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(crouchKey)) {
        isCrouching = false; 
        UpdateSpeed ();
    }
}

private void UpdateSpeed () {
    movementSpeed = isCrouching ? baseSpeed / 2
                  : isSprinting ? baseSpeed * 2
                  :               baseSpeed;
}
```